# Are questions that ask for help with specific chess sites, like chess.com and lichess.org, on topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope, closed-questions, specific-question, close-reasons

My question

> [How do I get the chess.com engine to list all the best moves?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/posts/34047/revisions) (I later deleted)

was closed by Brian Towers♦ who said

> This is Chess StackExchange, not the chess.com help center.

(**btw the answer is** to increase the number of lines. same as in lichess. i think the question could've been edited to be on-topic like ask about how to do computer analysis in general.)

And yet this is allowed:

> [How do I play 30 second games on chess.com?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29814/how-do-i-play-30-second-games-on-chess-com)

Why? What's the rule for this?

Note: I think resource recommendation questions like this [Play online live game against a friend with time odds?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/14736/play-online-live-game-against-a-friend-with-time-odds) are ok

Comment: Update: the 30 second thingy was closed.

Comment: If the grounds for closing have been changed, the exact new reasons must be clearly posted at the original question, so the questioner can understand and possibly amend the question.

Answer (score 4):

From the [help center](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic),

> In general, questions which can be answered without significantly referencing any chess-specific data (other than whatever data was presented by the question) are off-topic. Chess-specific data means data that would be directly invalidated without reference to chess.

So the three questions are off-topic. The first two are about how to interact with the interface of a chess website and the last is a software recommendation. If you exchange "chess" with "tic-tac-toe" they would still be meaningful questions, they aren't about chess.

Comment: if they are all off-topic, then how come some are not closed or deleted?

Comment: @BCLC The community or a moderator has to vote to close them. Why that did not happen I don't know. I've just flagged both as off-topic.

Comment: wati why do you think 'Play online live game against a friend with time odds?' is off-topic?

Answer (score 2):

While they may be technically off-topic, perhaps we could make some exceptions. Seeing as how they, and many other questions, are not closed, it certainly seems that some selection of them remain accepted by the community. Lichess and chess.com are the top two chess sites, along with others such as chess24. It may be time to rewrite that section of the rules.